# Why doesn't the function change the given Node (list)?

Tags: c#, nodes

I currently have this function in my code:

```
public static void GoToNextNode(Node<int> head)
{
    head = head.GetNext();
}
```

And this is my main function:

```
Node<int> a1 = new Node<int>(5);
Node<int> a2 = new Node<int>(5,a1);
GoToNextNode(a2); // <---
```

However, after executing the line marked by the arrow, it doesn't move throughout the node list to the next object.

The function itself works, but it will work in the main program only if I make it return the next value instead:

```
public static Node<int> GoToNextNode(Node<int> head)
{
    return head.GetNext();
}
```

And then change the main function to:

```
Node<int> a1 = new Node<int>(5);
Node<int> a2 = new Node<int>(5,a1);
a2 = GoToNextNode(a2); // <---
```

Any ideas why the first option doesn't work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure, but might be because of your first call makes a copy of your node

Comment: To do what I'm supposing you want to do, I guess the `GoToNextNode` code should be: `head = head.GetNext();`, returning `void`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you pass an object to a method, you don´t actually pass that object itself, but only a *reference* to it, to that method. As this reference itself is passed by *value* any modifications to it within that method aren´t reflected on the outside. This is in no way different from the following:

```
DoSomething(int i) 
{
    i = 3;
}
```

You could of course re-assign any new value to `i` in the method. Any client-code however won´t reflect this at all, it will still only see the exact same value passed into the method. Or in other words: what you do with `i` in `DoSomething` stays at `DoSomething`, no-one will every notice it.

To be able to change a reference, you need the [`ref`-keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref). In short it lets you modify the *reference* passed to your method, so that after calling `GotoNextNode` the parameter `a2` references another instance:

```
public static void GoToNextNode(ref Node<int> head)
{
    head = head.GetNext();
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
GoToNextNode(ref a2);
```

When - on the other hand - you only want to modify the *members* of an instance, you don´t need ref, as shown here:

```
void DoSometjng(MyClass a)
{
    a.MyProperty = newValue;
}
```

As you see, you´re not re-referencing `a`, but just *modifying* the underlying object. Now whoever uses this code will of course see the `newValue` within that object.

Comment: The type `Node<T>` isn't passed by reference by default?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Nothing is passed by reference in C#, everything is passed by value - unless you tell your program to do so by using `ref`.

Comment: Since when that? Did C# change during the last year so much that all objects are passed by value now?

Comment: C# had always passed by value unless told not to,  it consisted safer

Comment: You´re mixing two things here. Of course you can modify the members of the object passed as reference to a method. However you can´t change the **reference** within a method, unless you´re using `ref`. Thus a reference itself - and that´s what you pass to a method - is allways passed as **value**.

Comment: Following this logic I just created a function to test this. All it did was to insert numbers into an array. There I didn't need to put the ref keyword. Why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EmanuelL By adding numbers to the array you don´t change the **reference** to that array, but just its content (its members). To do this you don´t need the ref-keyword, every modification made to the *instance* which is referenced are reflected in all references to it of course.

Comment: I was really mixing things. [**Passing by reference** is not the same than **reference types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Passed values changed inside a method are not changed outside of the method unless, you use ref or out, which let's the compiler know that you want changes in the value inside of the method to effect the value of the variable out of scope .

to change the value of your first node example

```
Public static void GoToNext ( ref Node <int> head)
{
head = head.getNext ();
}
```